# Need to install applications on Cent OS supercomputer that has no connection to the internet

Tags: centos, yum

I've inherited a project where I need to install a number of applications onto a brand new supercomputer running CentOS.  For instance, I need to install Git and Bugzilla and other things on there that I'm used to using yum for (where it fetches things via a connection to the internet). I have a Mac OSX for my work laptop and I'm connecting to the super computer's command line via an ethernet connection.

What's the best way to approach this kind of project?  Installing all the CPAN modules that Bugzilla needs by hand seems painful.  Is there a better way approach to something like this?

Comment: You really have this thing air-gapped and it's not connected to any network at all?

Comment: Yes.  I'm afraid so.  Nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are connected via ethernet you can setup a repo for your own and rsync all files from an offical mirror to your local repo.

How to setup your own repo is described in centos wiki http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror

Comment: This is a great idea.  Beats doing things via VM or building by hand.  Plus, it's something I can maintain in house over time.  Thanks!